# How can i Initialize StructureMap within windows service

Tags: web-services, service, windows-services, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I would like to ask how can i initialize StructureMap within windows service?

the error i am getting is: 
The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the problem, add a default constructor to the type, or pass an instance of the type to the host.

i have created a windows form application using visual studio 2008.
in this application i have added those files:

1. service.cs
2. MyPrivateServiceService.cs
3. AppRegistry.cs

code:
 public class MyPrivateServiceService

```
{
    private readonly IAdapter adapter;
    public MyPrivateServiceService(IAdapter adapter)
    {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }
    [OperationBehavior]
    public void DoSomthing()
    {
        var res = adapter.GetById(1);
    }
}
partial class Service : WcfServiceBase
{
    static Service()
    {
        GlobalContext.Properties["PROGRNAAM"] = ServiceNaamKort;
        log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Service));
        InitializeIoc();
    }
    private static void InitializeIoc()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
        {
            x.AddRegistry<AppRegistry>();
        });
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnStart(args);
            host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyPrivateServiceService));
            host.Open();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Fatal("....", ex);
            DisposeHost();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
public class AppRegistry : Registry
{
    public AppRegistry()
    {
        Scan(s =>
        {
            s.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you

Ori

Answer (score 0):

I have found this link: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/07/30/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf/

it works when i add new constructor like this one:

```
public CustomerSearchService()
: this(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICustomerRepository>(), 
    ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICustomerSummaryMapper>())
```

{
}

i have tried to implement the StructureMapServiceHostFactory, but i am using windows service, any idea how to initialize the StructureMapServiceHostFactory with the service.cs ?

thank you

Ori